# Обработка текстового файла с использованием Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

День добрый! Недавно стал изучать Stream API java. Изучил пару статей

[Vedenin/java_in_examples](https://github.com/Vedenin/java_in_examples/blob/master/stream_api/src/com/github/vedenin/rus/stream_api/readme.md)

[Полное руководство по Java 8 Stream API](https://annimon.com/article/2778)

Есть задача – считать строку из файла csv, разбить на значения, преобразовать в double,сложить в ArrayList. Пока решил задачу вот таким способом:

```
package Practice.First;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Parse {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {// Создание стрима из файла
        //Создание тестового файла
        File file = new File("TestParse.csv");
        file.deleteOnExit();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
        out.println("21.5,-51.7,1.0");//Double
        out.close();

        ArrayList<Double> arrayListDouble1 = new ArrayList<>();

        Arrays.stream( parseSTR( readAllBytes( file.getAbsolutePath() )))
                .map(Double::valueOf)
                .forEach(arrayListDouble1::add);

        System.out.println(arrayListDouble1);

        //Stream реализация
        Stream<String> streamFromFiles = Files.lines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()));

        System.out.println("streamFromFiles = " +
                streamFromFiles
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
    }

    private static String[] parseSTR(String str) {
        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
        String[] array = new String[stk.countTokens()];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = stk.nextToken();
        }

       // array = IntStream.range(0, stk.countTokens()).mapToObj(i -> stk.nextToken()).toArray(String[]::new);
        return array;
    }

    private static String readAllBytes(String filePath) {
        String content = "";
        try {
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }

}
```

Как выполнить данную задачу ипользуя StreamAPI? У меня не получается разделить загруженный с файла поток ["21.5,-51.7,1.0"] на отдельные значения в этом потоке. Как это сделать правильно.Как с потока сложить данные сразу в ArrayList? С остальными преобразованиями вроде всё понятно...Спасибо

PS Я недавно изучаю Java. Буду признателен, если укажите на ошибки при написании кода и т.д и т.п .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()))
     .flatMap( s -> Stream.of(s.split(",")))
     .map(Double::valueOf) 
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

С пояснениями:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())) //получаем стрим строк из файла
     .flatMap( s -> Stream.of(s.split(","))) // из каждой строки создаем стрим по делиметру
     .map(Double::valueOf) // каждое слово преобразуем к double
     .collect(Collectors.toList()); // собираем все в лист
```

Вроде так, писал без IDE так, что мог очепятаться.

Comment: Благодарю, все работает как надо.С можете порекомендовать какую-нибудь литературу по StreamApi, Lambda ? Читаю "Лямбда выражения .." Р.Уорбэртона - не очень понятно.

Comment: @Scragме они дались только после того, как начал ими пользоваться. Т.е. придумайте себе несколько задачек и решите их

Comment: ток вроде надо stream полученный из Files.lines обернуть в try-with-resources, чтобы закрывать файл за собой

Comment: не обязательно. Files.lines содержит закрытие BufferedReader если вылетят ошибки + сам возвращаемый стрим выглядит так  br.lines().onClose(asUncheckedRunnable(br))